# OAuthException when doing a facebook query

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I get the following error when trying this URL (just pasting it in a browser to check for output):

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=London&type=event&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

```
{    "error": {
      "message": "(#200) Must have a valid access_token to access this endpoint",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 200
    }
}
```

I got the `ACCESS_TOKEN` by following [this guide](http://awpny.com/how-to-facebook-access-token/). What am I doing wrong?

---

**Solution**

Thanks to [Rahil Arora](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1382832/rahil-arora) for the tip. Here is how I printed out my access token:

I put this on my private website. After I set the public URL of the FB app to point to that webpage, I simply clicked on the "login" button. Then there was a popup that allowed my app to access my personal data, and voila! It printed out the access token ;)

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
        <button id="login">Login to FB</button>
        <p>Access token: <span id="token"></span>
        <script>
        $(function() {

            FB.init({
              appId      : 'APP-ID', // App ID
              channelUrl : '', // Channel File
              status     : true, // check login status
              cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
              xfbml      : true,  // parse XFBML
              oauth      : true
            });

            FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function (response) {
              if (response.status === 'connected') {
                $('#token').html(response.authResponse.accessToken);
              }
            });

            $('#login').click(function(e) {
              FB.login();
            });

        });
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an [App Token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#apptokens). What you really need for the request is a [User Access Token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#usertokens).

The search API documentation says that:

> - Searches across page and place objects requires an app access token.
> - All other endpoints require a user access token.

Since you are searching for an event, you need a User Access Token. You can find more details about generating User Access Tokens [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#usertokens).

To test you queries, you can use the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=search?q=London&type=event). It provides you with a User Access Token by default for testing you queries.

Comment: Strange, I thought that public events fell under place objects? The docs on user access tokens read: 
`This kind of access token is needed any time the app calls an API to read, modify or write a specific person's Facebook data on their behalf. ` 

But I only want to read public data

Comment: Still, you need an Access Token as all Graph API searches require an Access Token. It's mentioned in the documentation. I tried out the same query with a user access token (on Graph API explorer) and it's working perfectly for me.

Comment: @ArnabDatta Were you able to fix the problem?

Comment: Rahil is correct, you need the User Access Token do achieve this.

Comment: Thanks for backing me up. @Tobi

Answer (score 0):

As the error message stated, the provided access token is not valid. If you provide an access token, it must be valid. Otherwise you get an error. If you want read public data w/o any token, leave the access token away entirely.

access token are only valid for a limited period of time. They expire after some time, which can be days or hours. You need to check and ask for a new access token, if it is expired. Usually you get a different and particular error code on this.

The user, which owns the data you want access, must have granted access to your app first. That's how you retrieve the access token by OAauth. Once he revokes this grant, your access token is invalidated. The user can do this at any time w/o your notification, leaving you alone with the above error message.

Bottom line: you need to dig in to that and investigate further what actually has happened:

1. you actually have an invalid (never valid) token
2. your token was valid but has been revoked
3. ...